# If the condition of an if statement is true, can you stop execution?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement, execution

If a condition is met, I want to be able to stop the execution of the program. This is a project for school, so I cannot change it from an IF statement.

```
    while (peopleInGroup[0] > i) {
        ageOfPeopleInGroup.push(prompt("How old are you? " + i));
        i++;
    }
    //If any one of the people in the group is under 13, then all members are prompted the rules of the movie thearter. If statements were choosen because it's possible none of the people in the group are under 13.//
    if (ageOfPeopleInGroup[0]< 13) {
        alert("If someone is under the age of 13, they must be accompanied by someone 18 years of age or older.")
```

Comment: you can use break statement to get out of loop and use return statement to exit out

Comment: just break out the loop as above

Comment: Well the if would need to be in the while loop....

Comment: You would have to put the if condition inside the while loop and when the condition is met just break /return from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a couple of things wrong here.

First your loop won't iterate because you're always pointing at the first element (`peopleInGroup[0]`). You would need a variable to iterate (`peopleInGroup[i]`). But a while loop isn't the most natural fit for this, there are better array iteration methods like `for`, `forEach` etc.

Next your if condition is outside the loop, you would put that inside it and use `break` to exit the loop if a condition is met, e.g:

```
while(i < peopleInGroup.length) {
  if (peopleInGroup[i].age > 13) {
    hasUnderagePeople = true;
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

However there are array methods to tell you if a condition is met by an item, such as [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/some):

```
const hasSomeUnderagePeople = peopleInGroup.some(person => person.age <= 13);
```

Which is equivalent in old style javascript to:

```
var hasSomeUnderagePeople = peopleInGroup.some(function(person) {
  return person.age <= 13;
});
```

And then your prompt:

```
if (hasSomeUnderagePeople) {
  alert('If someone is under the age of 13, they must be accompanied by someone 18 years of age or older.')
}
```

This is assuming that each item in the array is an object with an age property. It's unclear what your items actually consist of.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much you can alter of the structure, but this may be something what you want:

```js
var numOfPeople=parseInt(prompt("How many persons are there?"));
var underaged=false;
var ages=[];
for(var i=0;i<numOfPeople;i++){
   var age=parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"));
   ages.push(age);
   if(age<13)
       underaged=true;
}

if(underaged)
    alert("Blablabla, 13, blablabla...");
```

Here the idea is that all of the ages will be asked for, and if any of them is below 13, that appears in the variable `underaged`, and results in displaying the alert only at the end, and only once, for the whole group.

If you do not want to store all the ages, then it makes more sense to use `while`+`break`:

```js
var numOfPeople=parseInt(prompt("How many persons are there?"));

while(numOfPeople>0){
    if(parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"))<13){
        alert("Blablabla, 13, blablabla...");
        break;
    }
    numOfPeople--;
}
```

This variant starts asking for the ages, and if there is an underaged person, displays the alert and stops asking. If all ages are fine, it just ends without showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
while (peopleInGroup[0] > i) {
  var age = prompt("How old are you? " + i);
  if(age < 13){
    //If any one of the people in the group is under 13, then all members are prompted the rules of the movie thearter. If statements were choosen because it's possible none of the people in the group are under 13.//
    alert("If someone is under the age of 13, they must be accompanied by someone 18 years of age or older.")
    break;
  } else {
    ageOfPeopleInGroup.push(age);
  }
  i++;
}
```